# When is the trader open?

Tags: soul-harvester

Under the "Dungeon" tab it usually says:

> The trader is currently closed, sorry!

One time I looked, it said I could trade 1,000,000 souls for 100 magic (those numbers may be wrong, but something like that).  I am now at the point where I usually have that many souls and could use the magic.

When is the trader available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [update reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/soulharvester/comments/1p9ccd/updates/), he appears randomly.

I have found that after enough time has passed (I don't know the exact conditions unfortunately), there is an upgrade that allows you to generate 1 magic/second - the same as the mana beast.